# ruby referring to deleted location on mac osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, shell, rvm

I installed rvm on my mac and used it for a while. However, wanted to start a new project with a clean slate and deleted the .rvm folder in my home directory.

If I now run 
`which ruby` 
it shows
`/usr/bin/ruby`
however, if I run 
`ruby -v`, it shows:
`/Users/kiran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby file not found`

I donot have an alias in any of my bash* files. How is tis happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the PATH resolution to commands is cached, you need to run:

```
hash -r
```

It will clean the cache.